# php condition inside array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

In the code below, I need to be able to set a different where condition when {VarName} is empty (blank or null).

Is it possible to have an if condition inside the array definition? Alternatively, can I have the validation inside of the sql query?

```
$col["editoptions"] = array(
             "value"=>$str, 
             "onchange" => array(
              array(
              "sql"=> "select distinct place as k, place as v from mytable                                       
                      WHERE Name = '{VarName}' 
                      AND Area = '{VarArea}'
                      ORDER BY place",
              "update_field" => "Localidade" )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary in the array definition, which looks like this:

`condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false`

e.g.,

`1 == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no'; // evaluates to 'yes'`

So in your case:

```
$col["editoptions"] = array(
    "value"=>$str, 
    "onchange" => array(
        array(
            "sql"=> empty($VarName) ?
                "YOUR ALTERNATIVE SQL HERE" : 
                "select distinct place as k, place as v from mytable                                       
                      WHERE Name = '{VarName}' 
                      AND Area = '{VarArea}'
                      ORDER BY place",
              "update_field" => "Localidade"
        )
    )
);
```

To make your array definition tidier you should consider putting your SQL in a variable and referencing the variable in the array def:

```
$sql = empty($VarName) ?
    "YOUR ALTERNATIVE SQL HERE" : 
    "select distinct place as k, place as v from mytable                                       
        WHERE Name = '{VarName}' 
        AND Area = '{VarArea}'
        ORDER BY place";
$col["editoptions"] = array(
    "value"=>$str, 
    "onchange" => array(
        array(
            "sql" => $sql,
            "update_field" => "Localidade"
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Matt says you can build inside array like below.

```
$VarName1 = null;

$col["editoptions"] = array(
    "value"=> 'value', 
    "onchange" => array(
     array(
     "sql"=> "select distinct place as k, place as v from mytable                                       
             WHERE Name = " . ( $VarName1 ? "'{VarName1}'" : "'{VarName2}'" ) .     
             "AND Area = '{VarArea}'
             ORDER BY place",
     "update_field" => "Localidade" )));
```

It would be better if you generate the sql in a string using condition in another variable like below for maintain easily.

```
$sql = "select distinct place as k, place as v from mytable                                      
WHERE Name = ";
if( $VarName1 ){
    $sql .= "'{VarName1}'";
}
else{
    $sql .= "'{VarName2}'";
}
$sql .=   "AND Area = '{VarArea}' ORDER BY place";
```